# How to take an html value and make it a java variable

Tags: java, jsp

Basically I need to save value  in a variable like x.

```
<select id='selected'>
<option value="1">1 Days</option>
<option value="3">3 Days</option>
<option value="5">5 days</option>
<option value="8">8 Days</option>
<option value="20000">All</option>
</select>
```

I am in a jsp file and i need the value you select (on the drop down) to save in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can submit and receive data to servlet.

**index.html**

```
<form action="NewServlet" method="post">
    <select id='selected' name="Days">
        <option value="1">1 Days</option>
        <option value="3">3 Days</option>
        <option value="5">5 days</option>
        <option value="8">8 Days</option>
        <option value="20000">All</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**NewServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/NewServlet"})
public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        String days = request.getParameter("Days");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<h1>Days value :  " + days + "</h1>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Selected Item change form submit example .

**Jsp file:**

```
    <form action="servlet" method="POST">
        <select name="select" id="select" onchange="this.form.submit()">
           <option value="1">1 Days</option>
           <option value="3">3 Days</option>
           <option value="5">5 days</option>
           <option value="8">8 Days</option>
           <option value="20000">All</option>
        </select>
        </br>
        <c:out value="${selected}"></c:out>
    </form>
```

**Servlet.class**

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   String select = request.getParameter("select");
   request.setAttribute("selected", select);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/select.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```